# How to catch possible errors in Json format?

Tags: java, android, json, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to make an app using Microsoft's computer vision API. I wanted to catch the error by getting its returned Json. Here is the link of the API...https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa

Here is my code...Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);

    mEditText.setText("");
    if (e != null) {
        mEditText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        this.e = null;
    } else {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        AnalysisInDomainResult result2 = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisInDomainResult.class);

        mEditText.append("Image format: " + result2.metadata.format + "\n");
        mEditText.append("Image width: " + result2.metadata.width + ", height:" + result2.metadata.height + "\n");
        mEditText.append("\n");

        //decode the returned result
        JsonArray detectedCelebs = result2.result.get("celebrities").getAsJsonArray();
        if(result2.result != null){
           mEditText.append("Celebrities detected: "+ detectedCelebs.size()+"\n");

            for(JsonElement celebElement: detectedCelebs) {
                JsonObject celeb = celebElement.getAsJsonObject();
                mEditText.append("Name: "+celeb.get("name").getAsString() +", score" +
                        celeb.get("confidence").getAsString() +"\n");
            }
        }
        mEditText.setSelection(0);
    }
```

Comment: Add a `try..catch..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android/blob/master/ClientLibrary/lib/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/vision/rest/WebServiceRequest.java#L151), if the service returns an error, a simple (and terse) `Exception` is thrown.

If you're modelling your code off the [Sample App](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android/blob/fcb50eaa6382acf259d3065f17c880080ceeb093/Sample/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/visionsample/AnalyzeInDomainActivity.java), you will see that the code looks like this:

```
private class doRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    // Store error message
    private Exception e = null;

    public doRequest() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            return process();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.e = e;    // Store error
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        super.onPostExecute(data);
        ...
    }
```

The `e` field will let you find the HTTP status code, but the error details are already lost.  For that you should raise an issue on [that library](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android/issues).

Comment: ok thank you @cthrash